# I cannot implement custom error page functionality in C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

`web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" >defaultRedirect="/Error/Error404"
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/Error404" />
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error/Error403" />
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error/Error500" />
        <error statusCode="501" redirect="/Error/Error500" />
        <error statusCode="502" redirect="/Error/Error500" />
        <error statusCode="503" redirect="/Error/Error500" />
        <error statusCode="504" redirect="/Error/Error500" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

`Tab_Error_404.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>404 - Page Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Nep-Users">
        <div class="grd-form standard-form">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <!--<img src="~/Content/_Images/neptronic logo.png" alt="Company Logo" class="company-logo" />-->
                <img src="~/Content/_Images/nepLogo.PNG" alt="Company Logo" class="company-logo" />
            </div>
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img src="~/Content/_Images/404.jpg" alt="404 - Page Not Found" class="error-image" />
            </div>
            <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
            <p>The resource you are looking for could not be found.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return View("~/Views/Sections/ErrorPage/Tab_Error_404.cshtml");
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Error403()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 403;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return View("~/Views/Sections/ErrorPage/Tab_Error_403.cshtml");
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Error500()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return View("~/Views/Sections/ErrorPage/Tab_Error_500.cshtml");
    }
}
```

`RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Error404",
            url: "Error404",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Error403",
            url: "Error403",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error403" }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Error500",
            url: "Error500",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error500" }
        );
```

`Gloabal.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();

    LogException(exception);

    var httpException = exception as HttpException;

    if (httpException != null)
    {
        int httpStatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();

        // Clear response and error state
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        HandleHttpException(httpStatusCode);
    }
}

private void HandleHttpException(int httpStatusCode)
{
    IController controller = new ErrorController();

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

    switch (httpStatusCode)
    {
        case 404:
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error404");
            break;

        case 403:
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error403");
            break;

        case 500:
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error500");
            break;

        default:
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error404");
            break;
    }

    var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
    controller.Execute(requestContext);
}

private void LogException(Exception exception)
{
    // Log the exception using NLog
    var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Error(exception, "An error occurred");
}
```

After conducting all the necessary steps, when I intentionally trigger a 404 Not Found error, I continue to receive the default error page.

[The default error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEZpl.png)

If I intentionally trigger the route

```
return Redirect("/Error/Error403");
```

I see the my expected page.

I'm uncertain about the cause of the issue despite despite exploring all possible solution.

Would anyone be able to offer assistance? A little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be performing redirects for errors because it prevents accurate HTTP status codes being returned to the client; e.g. a Not Found response should be HTTP 404, but your `web.config` and code will do a HTTP 302 Found redirect to _another_ page which returns 404 - thus giving the browser the impression the redirect failed...